# Construct function from integral values

Tags: curve-fitting

From measurements (only) the values $a_i =\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x) dx$ for some sequence of (equispaced) $x_i$ are known about a non-negative function $f$. What would be techniques to find a reasonably smooth approximation to $f$?

Comment: There are many.  Your choice depends on what you know or assume about $f$.  What can you tell us about it?

Comment: Not much I'm afraid. In my case $f$ should be non-negative and continuous.

Comment: The non-negativity is a strong criterion: you should mention it in the post.  It guarantees that the sequence $(a_i)$ will be monotonically non-decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a simple solution myself:

Let $F(x) := \int_{x_0}^x f(y) dy$, then $F(x_i) = \int_{x_0}^{x_i} f(x) dx =  \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} a_j$. From these values I can interpolate $F$ (e.g. by splines) and then $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x)$ will have the desired properties.

Comment: It might or might not have all the desired properties.  You might find that your estimate of $f$ varies wildly, especially if you attempt a polynomial interpolation that runs through all the data you have about $F$.

Comment: I decided to use [Monotonic Cubic Splines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html) for interpolation of $F$ and the result looks ok to me.